# How to find a particular attribute value in comparing rows and columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
no tot place1   place2
1  1    colombo  negombo
1  2    negombo  kandy
1  3    kandy    colombo
2  1    colombo  kandy
2  2    kandy    jafna 
2  3    jafna    negombo
3  1    jafna    kaduwela
3  2    kaduwela jafna
4  1    trico    colombo
```

In this, I want to get `no` who is having the same `place1` and `place2`.

Example:

`no` 1 has total 3 `tot` and its `place1` and `place2` is equal because it's `'Colombo'` (comparing columns and row).

But `no` 2 doesn't have the same `place1` and `place2`.

How to retrieve data like that with a query?

Comment: PL/SQL specifically? Not just a query?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i just want the query

Comment: Can you show your expected results?  I'm not completely understanding...

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  no 1,3,colombo   3,2,jafna

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  i just want Colombo Colombo there are 3 trips bt one trip number but in the second one 3 trips one trip number bt destination is not == to departure Colombo to Negombo  but I want to retrieve same destination and departure with total num of trips

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the lists in `place1` to match the lists in `place2` for each `no`.

If so, you can use `listagg()`:

```
select no, listagg(place1, ',') within group (order by place1) as places
from t
group by no
having listagg(place1, ',') within group (order by place1) = listagg(place2, ',') within group (order by place2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the terminal places of that journeys (or what they are). Order from start to destination and once vice versa. The terminals will have a `ROW_NUMBER()` of 1. Use `PLACE1` for the terminals for the first order and `PLACE2` for the second. Then join the results and compare the the terminals. If they are equal you got a round trip and can return the respective `NO`.

```
SELECT X.NO
       FROM (SELECT NO,
                    PLACE1 PLACE,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NO
                                       ORDER BY TOTN ASC) RN
                    FROM ELBAT) X
            INNER JOIN (SELECT NO,
                               PLACE2 PLACE,
                               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NO
                                                  ORDER BY TOTN DESC) RN
                               FROM ELBAT) Y
                       ON Y.NO = X.NO
       WHERE X.RN = 1
             AND Y.RN = 1
             AND X.PLACE = Y.PLACE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d59c0cd4a6f8186db959fb09bd5f657)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT A.*
  FROM A A
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM B B
                    WHERE A.A = B.A)
```